# Creating a subfloor where a fireplace used to be

Tags: fireplace

I've got to fill in and put a subfloor where they removed tiles and Bricks used to be. What I have are a mixture of 2x10 on the left, concrete blocks in the center and bricks on the right all at different levels. I'm thinking of laying 6 mil plastic and creating a leveled out cavity and then putting more plastic on top of that to layer some support slats with a 3/4 in sheet of plywood for the subfloor. **Big question is what do I use to fill in that cavity?** The deepest trough in the center will be an inch and a half with the bricks and the 2x12s being roughly the same height Within a half inch.

CMUs that go below grade in the crawlspace are below the bricks on the right and the exposed CMUs in the center. The 2x10s along the left are resting on the CMUs in the center and extend beneath the subfloor to the left. I assume they are supported by a floor joist.

[image]

Cut out the.pieces for screening whatever I wind up using to fill and cross members to lay atop the newly flattened and filled region. The plan is plastic sheeting to separate wood from the poured filler.
[image]

Comment: What is below all this masonry?

Comment: Yeah, I can't make a suggestion without knowing what's below. For me this isn't a matter of _filling_, but of _rebuilding_, with proper insulation and moisture management.

Comment: I can't quite tell from the picture.: what's the black thing poking up out of the brick?

Comment: That's just a crowbar. Not part of the floor

Comment: The way you have it looks like that would be perfectly acceptable for supporting the new wooden flooring (assuming your wooden supports are firmly attached to the floor below and are level & make the new floor flush with the old floor. I don't think you'd need to fill it at all.TBH, it doesn't look like there's anything separating the existing flooring from the brick, so any vapor/moisture barrier here won't help all that much in the grand scheme of things, in my opinion.